# How to run a function only if it matches the specified URL in bash script?

Tags: json, linux, bash

I am doing a project which kinda behaves like autologin. Below is the bash script:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool type $WUSER
DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key Tab
DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool type $DECPASS
DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key Return
```

There will be a default URL for login page (eg: https://github.com/login), which will:

- automatically type in the username
- press tab key
- type in the password
- click enter upon the chromium startup.

The problem is, I want the function to run only if the login page matches the URL `https://github.com/login`. So, if I wanted to set any other website URLs as default it will not run, unless I navigate to the github login page.  Then only it runs. The thing I am trying to explain is like this line from a .json file.

```
"matches": ["https://github.com/login"]
```

Comment: `I just want the function to run only if it matches the URL` What does "it" in that sentence refers to? What is "it"? What is the entity that does the matching?  `is like this line from a .json file.` It's not a valid json. I can post `{"any": "json"}` if I want to, is this json anyhow relevant?

Comment: “it” refers to the function which is the code I provided. nah that json code line is just an example of my explanation. if the url matches with the URL specified in the json file, it will run the script.js. what i meant was I wanted a bash script line which will check if the URL matches with github login page, then it will run the function. else do nothing. sorry for the poor explanation, as I said i’m just a beginner.

Comment: I edited the question to make it easier to understand, IMHO.  As a new contributor, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you for helping. Yes, will do that. It was kind of urgent to get it done so I got no choice. I got to create an account and post a question on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, `if` can be used to check if your URL is valid or not.  Since you have not posted any code, I assume a lot of things, but it will demonstrate the idea.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
url="$1"
if [[ "$url" == "https://github.com/login" ]]
then
    echo "The url is valid, proceding..."
    # PUT YOUR CODE HERE
else
    echo "The url is not valid, stopping the script..."
    exit 1
fi
```

But since only `"https://github.com/login"` is valid, you could not ask it at all and hard code it in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
url="https://github.com/login"

# rest of the script follows
......
```

This is pretty basic in bash, you should read through a bash tutorial to get you started.

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for and it's working fine. Again, thank you so much.